# Download to iphone via iphone app

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, download

In my iPhone application i want to allow a user to download a file.(video file)
From a UIWebview i have linked download button to the video file.

Didnt worked !

Any ideas ?

Please help !

Comment: As always, showing your code is very helpful. As is being more specific about the way in which it failed than "didn't work." (In what format is your video encoded?)

Comment: I think there is a bug in your code, or you are missing some relevant methods.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not way of downloading a file from WebKit component the same way it's done on the Desktop. If you want to do something like this you should interface with webView by using something like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

so that you can download the file properly.